# How to remove the folder structure generated when building multiple html entry points using Vite.js?

Tags: vite, rollupjs

My current vite.config.js looks sorta of like this:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    assetsDir: './',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/html/main.html', import.meta.url)),
        mobile: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/html/mobile.html', import.meta.url)),
        config: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/html/config.html', import.meta.url)),
      },
      output: {
        dir: 'dist',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

So my project's current folder structure for organization reasons is:

```
src/
 |- components 
 |- hooks
 |- pages
   `- Config
     `- index.tsx
   `- Main
     `- index.tsx
   `- Mobile
     `- index.tsx
 |- html/
 | `- config.html
 | `- main.html
 | `- mobile.html
```

My build(dist) folder structure is:

```
dist
 |- [...bunch of js files]
 | src/
    |- html/
    | `- config.html
    | `- main.html
    | `- mobile.html
```

My ideal final folder structure goal would be:

```
dist
 |- [...bunch of js files]
 |- config.html
 |- main.html
 |- mobile.html
```

I know I can just re-structure the project folder structure by putting the HTML files outside the src folder, in the root folder. But I'm aiming at being organized. I know this is possible using Webpack and I couldn't figure out how to do it on Vite.js with HTML files. Any direction or help would be awesome.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this Luis? I have the same requirements.

Comment: I did not. Since it was for internal use, I've built a script that goes through the dist folder and rearranges the files the way I want, it goes through each modified file and change import paths if needed and so on.